# gravity forms api get_entries limited to 20

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gravity-forms-plugin

This seems like an extremely simple question, but no matter how I slice it, Gravity Forms only shows 20 entries even when GFAPI::count_entries() returns 52.

Here's the code:

```
$form_id=16; 
$search_criteria = array( 'status' => 'active' );
$total_entries = GFAPI::count_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria );
echo '<h3>Count of entries: '.$total_entries.'</h4>';
// shows: Count of entries: 52 as expected

// great, now process each entry and get specific fields
$paging = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 60 );
$allentries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $paging );
echo '<h3>Count of entries: '.count($allentries).'</h4>';
// shows: Count of entries: 20

$entryid = 25; // known data item
$firstEntry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entryid );
echo '<h4>Name for 25: '.$firstEntry[20].'</h4>';
// shows: Name for 25: Todd

$entryid = 189; // known data item
$midEntry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entryid );
echo '<h4>Name for 189: '.$midEntry[20].'</h4>';
// shows: Name for 189: Steve

$entryid = 525; // known data item
$lastEntry = GFAPI::get_entry( $entryid );
echo '<h4>Name for 525: '.$lastEntry[20].'</h4>';
// shows: Name for 525: Graylin
```

I've added $page parameters, $search, etc., and nothing works...I only get the last 20 records submitted.

My goal is to cycle through the entries an get particular fields (e.g., firstname=[20], etc.).

Greatly appreciate the direction here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria, null, $paging );
```

Comment: Fantastic! That was the secret answer!!

Comment: That also answered another issue with $total_count. From what I can infer from this is all parameters need to be passed for GFAPI functions. Kinda strange, but important to know. Thanks VERY much!!

Comment: It's all fully documented here: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/api-functions/#get_entries